# Why is binary subtraction referred to as the invert-add-shift-add method?

Tags: binary-arithmetic

I'm being asked this question for my computer conceptes class, can't find anything about this in my text book, and have only been able to find half-baked answers googling it.

Why is binary subtraction referred to as the invert-add-shift-add method?

Comment: I think it's a silly question (on behalf of your instructor). I'd prefer the name "complement-add".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an excellent answer [here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_is_binary_subtraction_referred_to_as_the_invert-add-shift-add_method), which I summarize below.

Given two number $A,B$ in binary notation, we calculate $A-B$ by adding to $A$ the two's complement of $B$. Since the two's complement of $B$ is formed by inverting all bits of $B$ and adding $1$, one way to implement this idea is *invert* $B$, *add* the result to $A$, *shift* the carry $1$ bit (which will appear if $A\geq B$), and *add* it (i.e. $1$) to the result.

Comment: In addition to the above you can watch this video ([Two's Complement Part 2 - An Introduction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hof95YlLQk0)) on YouTube described the procedure clearly and completly!